# Proving using the definition of image and inverse image of a set under a function.

Tags: functions

a) If $f:A→B$ and $Z∈ℙ(A)$, show that Z⊆f<sup>-1</sup>(f(Z)).

b) Show that if $f:A→B$ is injective, then for all $Z∈ℙ(A)$, f<sup>-1</sup>(f(Z))=Z.

Comment: A solution to finding f^-1(f(Z)) would be appreciated.

Comment: Does $P(A)$ denote the power set of $A$?

Comment: @Dasherman. Yes it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) Let $x \in Z.$ Then $f(x) \in f(Z) \Rightarrow x \in f^{-1}(f(x)) \subseteq f^{-1}(f(Z)).$

(2) We know from (a)  that $Z \subseteq f^{-1}f(Z)).$ Now we want to prove the other inclusion. For this note that, since $f$ is injective, for any $x \in A, f^{-1}(f(x)) = \{x \}.$ In particular, for every $y \in f(Z), f^{-1}(y) \in Z.$

*EDIT:* $f^{-1}(f(Z)) := \{x \in A:f(x) \in f(Z)\}.$ Note that by (a), $Z \subseteq f^{-1}(f(Z))$ and by (b), if $f$ is injective then $Z = f^{-1}f(Z).$ But his is not true in general. The problem is that, we can say image of every $z \in Z$ is in $f(Z)$ but we don't know if there are other elements in $A$ which are mapped to $f(Z).$ For example, take $f: \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z, x \mapsto x^2$ and take $Z = \{1, 2 \}.$ Then $f(Z) = \{1, 4 \}.$ But we have $f(-1) = 1, f(-2) = 4$ and $-1, -2 \notin Z.$

Comment: @Guest: I have added some clarification regarding $f^{-1}(f(Z)).$ Feel free to ask if you have any doubt.